What's the purpose of temperature ratings of conductors (wires)?
In countries governed by the NEC (like the US), insulated wires typically have insulations with 60, 75 or 90°C temperature rating. Wires have listed ampacities based on their insulation and other factors. Obviously the purpose of limiting a wire's current is to prevent fires.
But what does the temperature in the insulation actually mean? For example, what does a 75-°C insulation (like THW) mean?
Also, why exactly do we have 60/75/90-°C insulations? There are some NEC articles which allow for 105 and 125°C insulations. But my point is, why are these numbers chosen? For example, why not 300 or 594°C?
Lastly, why does copper get dark when the wire is overloaded continuously? You may have seen this in old houses or where wires are overloaded or exposed to extreme heat.

Regarding the first question, I think it's the maximum allowed temperature the insulation can safely withstand. Is that correct?
Regarding the second question, and assuming the previous answer is correct, initially I thought about melting point and boiling point, which for copper is 1085°C and 2562°C respectively. So clearly that's not related.
I then thought about the insulation itself and not the conductor. Apparently, thermoplastics (common insulations) like PP and PE have melting points between 110 and 175°C. This seems more reasonable (110 is pretty close to the 90-°C insulations, probably with some safety margin). Is that correct?
And about the third question, since the melting point of copper is so high, I don't think it's the actual metal that gets dark/brown (in fact, the melting point may not even be related to this), but instead the inner layer of the insulation that melts/burns a bit, which then sticks to the outer layer of the metal. If this reasoning is correct, then scratching a bit of a darkish overloaded wire should reveal a bright copper again. I haven't done a test. Have you ever performed this?
Another possibility I've researched is the fact that when copper is heated in air, it oxidizes, forming the brownish color. But would this be applicable here? Since the metal is not in contact with air, it's surrounded by the insulation.

The plastic used for the insulation has a melting temperature. When it reached that temperature, it can flow and is no longer good as an insulator. The oxidation rate of copper increases with temperature. (I am not a qualified materials engineer.)

Totally bare copper wire gets dark with heat and time. The darkening, roughly speaking, is an oxidation rate that takes place at rates $\propto T^4$ (in theory anyway.)


I then thought about the insulation itself and not the conductor. Apparently, thermoplastics (common insulations) like PP and PE have melting points between 110 and 175°C. This seems more reasonable (110 is pretty close to the 90-°C insulations, probably with some safety margin). Is that correct?

It's likely that the plastic will degrade over time at temperatures substantially below the melting temperature. Even if the melting temperature is 175 C, 20 years of operation at 100 C might make the material hard and brittle, so that even a little motion breaks it and exposes the conductor, potentially leading to short circuits and fires.

The cables have ratings because if you don't have ratings they are unknown and you don't know where you can use the cable and under which conditions.
The insulation is made of different materials so it must be known what temperature is safe, before they degrade, emit dangerous fumes, or simply melt.
Also many cables bundled in tight enclosed space get hotter due to lack of cooling, compared to same cable alone in open air for example.
The cable resistance also depends on temperature. At higher temperature the resistance is higher so even more power gets dissipated as heat in the cable.
So same cable can be rated for different current depending on how much temperature rise is allowed, and the allowed temperature depends on where the cable is used and how well it is cooled.
The tables are just a handy tool for electricians etc. to know what cable you can use safely depending on how and where you intend to use the cable, without knowing the details or being an engineer doing actual thermodynamic simulations and modeling.

The thermal rating is the limit that guarantees the performance of the cable and its insulation. Above this, the cable will degrade and possibly fail. In what ways? The insulation can melt, become brittle, outgas; or its insulation strength will be weakened by some chemical change.
The ratings are divided into common thermal categories depending on how the wire is to be used. The least demanding category is residential wiring, which can make do with NM-B ('Romex') rated at 60 deg. C. More demanding applications like commercial, motor wiring, etc. will use higher ratings. (I'm waving hands a bit here - these ratings are spelled out in electrical codes.) Some specialty wire such as those used heaters will have very high temperature ratings.
Speaking of which, sometimes a higher temp rating will be chosen to allow a smaller gauge to be used. For example, I have a 1500W space heater that has a 6' #16ga cord, that's rated for 90 deg. C. The cord gets hot, and in fact I had one fail recently. I'll be looking for a 105 deg. C one to replace it (maybe a fool's errand, I know.)
For your question about why copper wires turn black, the copper oxidizes more readily when hot. It also becomes softer (anneals) and is more likely to break. Neither situation is good.

For that cord replacement, your much better choice is any temperature rated 14 AWG cord or even 12 AWG if you can find one. Why? Because most of the heat on the cord is not from the heater (except possibly within a couple of inches of the heater) - it is the resistance of the wire with 12A going through it. Larger wire = lower resistance.

The heater lead needs to fit the existing strain relief on the appliance, so I’m kinda stuck with #16 ga.  It melted then broke right at the plug though.

And the manufacturer using 16 AWG wire tells you just how penny-pinching they are. One more reason I despise 1500W plug-in space heaters.

Yep. The wire could even be iron core instead of pure copper, another way they economize.

The first two questions are interconnected. The temperature rating of electrical wire insulation dictates the maximum current the wire can carry safely. For instance, 1 AWG TW at 60°C can carry 110 amps, TWH at 75°C can carry 130 amps, and THHN at 90°C can carry 145 amps.
Additionally, the terminal connected to the wire should have a temperature rating that matches or exceeds that of the wire. For instance, if a 90°C wire is used for its higher current capacity, the terminals must also be rated at 90°C or above.
